# Quitting minibufer works no more in 24.5.1?

Tags: minibuffer, recursive-edit

In GNU Emacs 24.5.1, which comes with Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus the C-g does not abort the command like it used to do in earlier versions, which is annoying as it breaks the habit.

There is C-] command, which seemingly does the same thing, but keybindings help screen shows they are bound to the same command abort-recursive-edit.

How to return C-g it's previous behavior of aborting a command with input in minibuffer? Are there caveats in changing C-g?

**Update**: in `emacs -Q`, press C-x C-f as if to find some file, but then press C-g to abandon the attempt. "Quit" is seen briefly, but "Find file: ..." message is still there in minibuffer, while it is expected to go away, like is the case with C-] command. Of coure, C-x C-f is only an example. Same happens with other commands as well.

Comment: The question is not very clear. Please consider providing a recipe from `emacs -Q`, saying what you see and what you expected to see. Consider also filing an Emacs bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Updated. I am not sure whether this is a bug or some new feature.

Comment: `C-f` moves forward one character. Perhaps you meant `C-x C-f`? If so, what you describe is not what I see. Consider filing a bug report.

Comment: Sorry. Of course C-x C-f.